# Add css to IPython.display to make it 100% of parent

Tags: python, css, jupyter-notebook

I am displaying an image in a Jupyter notebook using the `IPython.display` library.

```py
activeViewFromArray = ipywidgets.Output()
with activeViewFromArray:
    display(PIL.Image.fromarray(array))
```

How do I add `css` to it to allow me to make the width of the `<img>` generated by this display call to be 100% of the parent container?

If I inspect the page, I can easily make it 100% manually by updating the style of the `<img>` tag to be `width:100%`

[image]

However, if I just set that within the css file, all `<img>` tags get a 100% width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be accopmplished by add a class to the parent and then accessing the `img` child of the parent in `css`

```py
activeViewFromArray = ipywidgets.Output()
activeViewFromArray.add_class('img_array')

with activeViewFromArray:
    display(PIL.Image.fromarray(array))
```

`CSS`

```css
.img_array img {
    width: 100%;
}
```